# Elastic-APM TransactionIgnoreUrls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elastic-apm

To lower the load of the apm logging we would like to exclude our monitoring urls.
I've tried to make that happen with TransactionIgnoreUrls in de config but for some reason, I can't get it to work. According to the docs I should provide a list of string.
Below is the configuration I used (one of my attempts).
What I would like to do is exclude the ping endpoint for starters but eventually end up with all endpoints containing `/status/` in the url

```
"ElasticApm__TransactionSampleRate": "1.0",
"ElasticApm__Enabled": "true",
"ElasticApm__Environment": "Development",
"ElasticApm__SecretToken": "some token",
"ElasticApm__ServerUrls": "serverurl",
"ElasticApm__VerifyServerCert": "FALSE",
"ElasticApm__ServiceName": "MyApi"
"ElasticApm__TransactionIgnoreUrls": [
  "*pin*"
],
```

Startup.cs

```
app.UseAllElasticApm(Configuration);
```

The above does not filter out our endpoint (also tried with `"ping"`, `"/ping"`, `"status"`, `"/status"` and lots of other possibilities) as it is still visible in the apm dashboard.

[image]

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The configs should be a comma separated string. I just looked at the docs and indeed it's a bit confusing. So it must be `"UrlToIgnore1, UrlToIgnore2"` (the agent will parse this internally) and not an array like `["UrlToIgnore1", "UrlToIgnore2"]`. So in your case it should be just `"*pin*"` and if you want to attach another value to ignore, just add it to the string after a comma (`,`).
2. Where do you put the configs you pasted here? This double underscore format is an environment variable which you set, right? If so, just put `"*pin*"` to `ElasticApm__TransactionIgnoreUrls`, In case you use `appsettings.json` here is how it should look:

```
"ElasticApm": {
  "TransactionIgnoreUrls": "*pin*"
}
```

Comment: The docs are far from clear. They say you can just add a part of the path, but did some testing to get both my endpoints excluded and even there I have to use wildcards `"*/status/*"`.

Comment: I've also noticed that I now have overwritten all the default values listed in the docs (favicon.ico, woff2, ...). Looking at that list, I see some values with double quotes. Is that correct or should they be wildcards since I got an item in my request list in elastic called `/hangfire1/js1790`

Comment: I opened a PR to make this better: https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-dotnet/pull/1514 Feel free to chime in on the PR.

To also answer your issues here: With the 1 comment I assume you refer to the example with `home/index` - that tries to show that the host and the query string is ignored, but does not say you can add part of the path - I changed the docs to describe this better - if you want to match on part of the path you need to use `*`. To the 2. comment: you are totally right, the double quotes were some leftover, I removed those. Also added a note about the default.

Comment: Thx. I already took a look in the source to get the correct default values.
All is working now as I want it to be.